# MVC Ajax Validation with server attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to be able to display validation errors with I do a Ajax post from a MVC form.  All the server validation is working fine, but when I post using a ajax post i cannot get the page to display any validation errors.  I have looked at other answers on stackoverflow but they seem convoluted and it seems that this problem must have been solved thousands of times.

Here is my c# server side view model:

```
    public class Card_TextViewModel:IValidatableObject
        {
            [Key]
            [Required]
            [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 2)]
            [Display(Name = "Product Code")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string Prod_Code { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
            [Display(Name = "Page 1 Text")]
            public string Page1Text { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
            [Display(Name = "Inside Text")]
            public string InsideText { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "User Name")]
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Export Date")]
            public DateTime? ExportDate { get; set; }

            public IList<Card_Text> Card_Text { get; set; }

            public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Prod_Code))
                {
                    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Prod_Code.Substring(0,1)))
                    {
                        yield return new ValidationResult("The product code cannot start with a space", new[] { "Prod_Code" });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my api code:

```
       public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAddExtra([Bind(Include = "Prod_Code,Page1Text,InsideText")] Card_TextViewModel viewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    return Json(new { success = false, message = "Request ajax request only" });

                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return Json(new { success = false, message = "Invalid data" });

                Card_Text card_Text = await db.Card_Text.FindAsync(viewModel.Prod_Code);

                if (card_Text != null)
                    return Json(new { success = false, message = string.Format("The product code {0} already exists", viewModel.Prod_Code) });

                card_Text = Mapper.Map<Card_TextViewModel, Card_Text>(viewModel);
                card_Text.UserName = User.Identity.Name;

                db.Card_Text.Add(card_Text);

                if (await db.SaveChangesAsync() == 0)
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = string.Format("Error creating product code {0}", viewModel.Prod_Code) });

                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
            }

            return Json(new { success = false });
        }
```

All the above is working fine and no problems, here is the javascript which post to the CreateAddExtra()

```
    (function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var successCount = 0;

            var addCreate = function () {
                var url = "https://localhost:44393/Card_Text/CreateAddExtra";
                var data = $("#create").serialize();

                $.post(url, data)
                    .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (data.success === true) {
                            successCount++;
                            $('#successCount').text(successCount);

                        } else {
                            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);

                            /*would like the unobtrusive javascript to display any valide errors that occurred on the post back, which are store in MVC ModelState
How do we activate unobtrusive javascript?
*/
                    }
                });

            return false;
        };

//just event for a button press
        $("#add").click(addCreate);
    });
})();
```

And here is the MVC html page code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "create" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Prod_Code)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prod_Code, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prod_Code, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Page1Text)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Page1Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", rows = 10, columns = 40 } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Page1Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InsideText)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InsideText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", rows = 10, columns = 40 } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InsideText, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <input type="submit" id="add" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" />
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Card_Text", null, new { id = "recordCount", @class = "btn btn-default" })
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>Records added:</span>
        <span id="successCount" class="text-danger">0</span>
    </div>
}
```

So, if a vaidation error occurs on post back how can I activate the unobtrusive javascript to show the error to the user?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this snippet from this [link](http://benfoster.io/blog/automatic-modelstate-validation-in-aspnet-mvc) that shows a simple technique to handle model state errors in ajax calls.

```
$(function () {
    // hijax the form
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var validator = $form.data("validator");

        if (!validator || !$form.valid())
            return;

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("index")",
            type: "POST",
            data: $form.serialize(),
            statusCode: {
                400: function(xhr, status, err) {                           
                    var errors = $.parseJSON(err);
                    validator.showErrors(errors);
                }
            },
            success: function() {
                // just reload the page for now
                location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for your time. tried the above snippet but the code never reaches my $.ajax call because of the line if (!validator || !$form.valid()) return; it is always undefined